# Join two tables and excluding

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

```
SELECT *
    From BANK.TXN_DLY
    WHERE TXN_DT BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-31'
        AND TXN_CD IN ('502');

SELECT *
    From BANK.TXN_DLY
    WHERE TXN_DT BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-31'
        AND TXN_CD IN ('510');
```

For example, I have these two tables. The 502 table has 200 rows. While 510 has 54 rows of which 50 can be found in 502 table. How do I form one table with 150 rows (reduces 502 table by 50) since it can be found in the 510 table?

Comment: Assuming the tables have the same columns, use 'EXCEPT' - 'select * from tablea EXCEPT select * from tableb`

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the SAS tag,  previous comment is only if you are using pass through SQL (think that's what it's called)

Comment: EXCEPT is valid in SAS SQL, but that's likely teradata sql as the dates are specified in a teradata format, not a SAS format.

Comment: EXCEPT works if the entire row matches, but with SELECT * the rows from the first query have TXN_CD = 502 and rows from the second have TXN_CD=510. @lookingforcodeassists This may require an "anti-join" (e.g. correlated NOT EXISTS) that identifies / removes matching rows based on only selected columns.

Comment: How can 50 rows have both `TXN_CD IN ('502')` and `TXN_CD IN ('510')`?

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata,
you can use **Minus/Except** and **Union** Keywords in the query for unique records.

For more details you can follow this [link](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/Srzze2BU1pNxIj00hVGntQ).